# cassandra client hector api java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4/Level

Tags: nosql, cassandra, hector, pelops

I am getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4/Level.

I'm not a java guy but can read code. What should i do to get rid of this exception?
This exception really have nothing to do with cassandra hector api, why is it bothering me?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the log4j jar on your classpath.  Specify the classpath with the `-cp` option on the `java` command when you run your app.